# Is it possible to use the FaceID unit IR sensor

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, face-id

Is it possible to explicitly access the IR camera of the **iPhone's FaceID** block using the **IOS SDK (Swift)**, for example, to get an infrared image, or do we have the ability to use only the general **FaceID** block without interacting with individual elements of this system?